# Create dimension with the last event that occurred

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set with a list of conversions and the events that led up to that conversion event. Each row is a different event with a conversion id that could be the same across multiple rows. I'm trying to mark the last event to occur for a particular conversion.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMMe3.jpg

Taking the first three rows, I would like to create a new dimension labeled "Last Event" that says whether this is the last event to occur before the conversion.

Don't really know where to start

I want that new dimension saying "Yes" or "No" if it was the last event to occur before the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using LOD. First create a calculation using the following formula:

```
 Calc1 = {FIXED [Conversion ID] : MAX([Event Date])}
```

Then Create a new calculation, which tags it as "yes" or "no" based on the first calculation.

```
Last Event = IF [Event Date]=[Calc1] then "yes" else "no" end
```

Comment: Last Event can be a boolean instead of a string - more efficient. The calc is then [Event Date]=[Calc1]. You can still assign an alias to display a different string label if desired

Comment: This approach works, but there is a hitch. If more than one event can occur on a day, then you can end up with multiple last events. If Events have an increasing sequential event id assigned, use that instead of Event Date to find instead the ID of the last event instead of the date.